# Margins of mdframed without any effect

Tags: indentation, double-sided, mdframed

This code

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{mdframed} %
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{boxedminipage}{1.0\textwidth}
Box of 100 \% width
\end{boxedminipage}

\begin{mdframed}[
  linecolor=black,%
  leftmargin =-1cm,
  rightmargin=+1cm,
]
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

does not show any margin on the left or right side.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the package ?

Version of mdframed is `2012/01/09 v1.2a`

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a bug.

Comment: @egreg: I'm glad that it isn't bug.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I'm glad too. :)

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yes. I was just surprised, that my code worked a few month ago.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It isn't a bug. You are using a documentclass with the default setting `twoside`. `mdframed` detects the working in `twoside` mode.

In this case you have two possibilities.

1. Use the option `usetwoside=false`. You can then work with `leftmargin`/`rightmargin`. But these margins will be equal on odd and even pages.
2. Use the options `innermargin`/`outermargin` to influence the behavior.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mdframed} %
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{boxedminipage}{1.0\textwidth}
Box of 100 \% width
\end{boxedminipage}

\begin{mdframed}[
  linecolor=black,%
  leftmargin =-1cm,
  rightmargin=+1cm,
  usetwoside=false,
]
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[
  linecolor=black,%
  innermargin =-1cm,
  outermargin =+1cm,
]
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
Sample Text to fill the line. Sample Text to fill the line.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]