# Draw a vertical line on the margin across several pages

Tags: margins

I want to draw a vertical line on the margin. The line may be able to continue to the next page(s) and must not cut with the end of the current page.

I'd prefer to use an environment or something like

```
\startline
% Text, math, figures etc
\stopline
```

With the line I'd mark a new or a fixed text for my co-authors.

I tried [receipt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41956/marking-conditional-versions-with-line-in-margin) of Matthew Leingang but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to `tex.stackexchange.com`! you may want to use `mdframed` package for your purpose.

Comment: This line is often called a "changebar", so perhaps the `changebar` package might be useful. It is rather old, so it is possible xelatex might not be supported out of the box, but it is alleged to work with both pdflatex and latex+dvips. There is also the `changes` package, for an alterative way to mark changes.

Comment: The `changebar` is exactly what I looked for. It is included into `texlive-latex-extra` package of Ubuntu 12.04 and works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `mdframed` package and only keep the left line visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[%
linewidth=1pt,
middlelinecolor= black,
middlelinewidth=0.4pt,
roundcorner=1pt,
topline = false,
rightline = false,
bottomline = false,
rightmargin=0pt,
skipabove=0pt,
skipbelow=0pt,
leftmargin=-1cm,
innerleftmargin=1cm,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt,
]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}
          \lipsum
    \end{mdframed}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: EDIT: you can adjust the line to enter left margin by using negative values for `leftmargin`.

Comment: Using negative values for `leftmargin` has no effect for two sided documents. Use `outermargin` instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41070/49283