# Why aren't leftmargin and rightmargin values (in mdfdefinestyle) having any effect on my theorem box?

Tags: margins, mdframed

I changed the value of *leftmargin* and *rightmargin* below from 1 cm to 15 cm, but there is no output change. My theorem box remains with the same width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{definitionSty}{
 backgroundcolor=blue!20,
 linewidth=1pt,
 innerleftmargin=1ex,
 innerrightmargin=1ex,
 innertopmargin=0.5ex,
 outerlinewidth=2,
 outerlinecolor=blue,
 innertopmargin=\topskip,
 splittopskip=\topskip,
 skipbelow=\baselineskip,
 skipabove=\baselineskip,
 ntheorem,
 leftline=true,
 rightline=true,
 leftmargin=1cm,
 rightmargin=1cm,
 frametitlerule=true,
 frametitlerulecolor=green,
 frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow,
 frametitlerulewidth=2pt}

\newcounter{definitionCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{definitionCounter}{chapter}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=definitionSty]{definition}[definitionCounter]{Defini\c{c}\~{a}o}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{Medição, grandeza e medida}

 \begin{itemize}
  \item medição: \textit{processo} pelo qual se mede algo
  \item grandeza: \textit{propriedade} quantificada por medição
  \item medida: \textit{resultado} do processo de medição
 \end{itemize}

\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my question:

[Margins of mdframed without any effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41066/margins-of-mdframed-without-any-effect)

Should I delete my question?

Comment: Since you were not easily able to locate the other questions, others might also have the sam difficulty, and perhaps find your question first.  From which, they can be redirected to the duplicate question so I would recommend you _not_ delete the question, and this question will be closed as a duplicate.