# Specifying the Length of a Bclogo without Enclosing It in a Minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, width, lengths, bclogo

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{bulgarianrose}{rgb}{0.28, 0.02, 0.03}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
%\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=red!55!bulgarianrose, epBord=3.5, arrondi=0, logo= ,
barre=none,
]
{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE{\textbf{\hfil ADJUST LENGTH BCLOGO \hfil}}}}
\end{bclogo}
%\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: Is it possible to *directly* specify the length of a `bclogo` without resorting to creating a `minipage` environment to contain it? If so, how may I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I found time to look at bclogo manual, you can try with `tcolorbox` because it seems that you don't need the logos defined in bclogo.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{bulgarianrose}{rgb}{0.28, 0.02, 0.03}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
%\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=red!55!bulgarianrose, epBord=3.5, arrondi=0, logo= ,
barre=none,
]
{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE{\textbf{\hfil ADJUST LENGTH BCLOGO \hfil}}}}
\end{bclogo}
%\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, colback=red!55!bulgarianrose,
boxrule=3.5pt, width=6.7cm, center, colupper=white, fontupper=\LARGE\bfseries, halign=center]
ADJUST LENGTH BCLOGO
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi

Comment: @mlchristians `bclogo` uses `mdframed` boxes, and this package knows when you use a `twoside` document class like in your case. In this case, `marginG` and `marginD` which are the options to define external margins in `bclogo` don't work. As an alternative I suggest `tcolorbox` or take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41066/1952.

Comment: Many thanks for the above comment.